# How to programmatically detect when an item is visible in a RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, mpandroidchart

My Android app has a RecyclerView with PagerSnapHelper. Each item has width and height as `match_parent`. Thus, only 1 view item stays on the page. I am interested in knowing when a particular view item is fully visible to the user. I want to perform some operation on that view.

### More Details

I am displaying charts in each view item using [MpAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library. I am also animating those charts. But since the RecyclerView loads some view items which are just adjacent to the currently visible view items, the animation happens before the view is even visible to the user. Thus, I need a callback method to surely know that a particular view item is visible to the user. So that I can animate my chart at that time.

### Code

I tried the following way to know for sure what's the currently visible item view. But it didn't solve my issue:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        if (newState != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
            View centerView = snapHelper.findSnapView(linearLayoutManager);
            BarChart barChart = centerView.findViewById(R.id.barChart);
            barChart.animateXY(ChartUtil.TIME, ChartUtil.TIME);
        }
    }
});
```

### Edit 1

The only known callback method for implementing the logic for each item view of a RecyclerView is `onBindViewHolder`. But the issue is if currently visible item position is (suppose) x, then RecyclerView also loads x+1 in advance so that the scrolling remains smooth. Due to this, the logic of animating the item view (in my case) is also getting executed before the view is even visible to the user. Thus, I need a callback method which tells me x position (or) item view is "visible" to the user.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After reading your question i got like you wanna show the item in recycle view after getting the data for specific view? right?

Comment: @ShravanJain No. I have the data upfront. The size of data remains fixed. But, since the RecyclerView loads few more items on the left/ right of the visible item before they're actually visible, hence the chart (inside item view of recyclerView) gets loaded and animates before it is actually visible to the user.

Hence, I want a way to know if the item view is visible to the user, so that at that moment I can animate the chart.

Comment: Okay. So you must have a class where you implemented the view for the specific item of recycle view. You can easily put the logic of this there.

Comment: The only known callback method for implementing my logic for each item view of a recyclerView is `onBindViewHolder`. But the issue is if currently visible item position is (suppose) x, then recyclerView also loads x+1 in advance so that the scrolling remains smooth. Due to this, my logic of animating the item view is also executed before the view is even visible to the user. Thus, I need a callback method which tells me if a particular view is "visible" to the user.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for answer on Kotlin, I can't check it quickly on Java now. But I hope it is also readable:

```
recycler_view.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        if (layoutManager.findViewByPosition(layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()).y == 0) {
            // Do what you need
        }
    }
})
```

So you just need to find offset for first visible position. And if it equals 0, then your item showing completely.

Comment: No. Please read my question completely. I have tried this method. It is not working. I request you to please add more substance to your answer if you think I am missing some pointers in my current implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll have to think more on your solution to tell you if it works on not. Allow me some time, please.

Comment: @MayankMohanUpadhyay it is ok. Please accept the answer if it works for you. Or feel free to ask if you get some questions.

Comment: No, this doesn't work for me. I have found a working solution today. I will post it.

Comment: @mumayank - did you post your solution for this? I have the exact same problem and I'm really curious of how you solved this :).

Comment: No, not yet. I had paused that work because of lack of an answer. Will search again.

Answer (score 4):

use this code:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager= (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    
    linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    
    linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    
    
    }
});
```